# OCaml use signature defined outside functor to limit visibility into produced module

Tags: module, ocaml, encapsulation, functor

I'm trying to write a functor that takes a pair of ordered things and produces another ordered thing (with ordering defined lexicographically).

However, I want the resulting "ordered type" to be abstract, rather than an OCaml tuple.

This is easy enough to do with an inline/anonymous signature.

```
(* orderedPairSetInlineSig.ml *)

module type ORDERED_TYPE = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end

module MakeOrderedPairSet (X : ORDERED_TYPE) :
  sig
    type t
    val get_fst : t -> X.t
    val get_snd : t -> X.t
    val make : X.t -> X.t -> t
    val compare : t -> t -> int
  end = struct
    type t = X.t * X.t

    let combine_comparisons fst snd =
      if fst = 0 then snd else fst

    let compare (x, y) (a, b) =
      let cmp  = X.compare x a in
      let cmp' = X.compare y b in
      combine_comparisons cmp cmp'

    let get_fst ((x, y) : t) = x

    let get_snd ((x, y) : t) = y

    let make x y = (x, y)
  end
```

I want to give my anonymous signature a name like `ORDERED_PAIR_SET_TYPE`  and move it outside the definition of `MakeOrderedPairSet`, like so (warning: not syntactically valid) :

```
(* orderedPairSet.ml *)

module type ORDERED_TYPE = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end

module type ORDERED_PAIR_SET_TYPE = sig
  type t
  type el

  val get_fst : t -> el
  val get_snd : t -> el
  val make : el -> el -> t

  val compare : t -> t -> int
end

module MakeOrderedPairSet (X : ORDERED_TYPE) :
  (ORDERED_PAIR_SET_TYPE with type el = X.t) = struct
    type t = X.t * X.t

    let combine_comparisons fst snd =
      if fst = 0 then snd else fst

    let compare (x, y) (a, b) =
      let cmp  = X.compare x a in
      let cmp' = X.compare y b in
      combine_comparisons cmp cmp'

    let get_fst ((x, y) : t) = x

    let get_snd ((x, y) : t) = y

    let make x y = (x, y)
  end
```

with `el` being an abstract type in the signature that I'm trying to bind to `X.t` inside the body of `MakeOrderedPairSet`.

However, I can't figure out how to fit everything together.

`(ORDERED_PAIR_SET_TYPE with type el = X.t)` is the most obvious way I can think of to say "give me a signature that's just like this one, but with an abstract type replaced with a concrete one (or differently-abstract in this case)". However, it isn't syntactically valid in this case (because of the parentheses). Taking the parentheses off does not result in a valid "module-language-level expression" either; I left it on because I think it makes my intent more obvious.

So ... how do you use a named signature to restrict the visibility into a [module produced by a functor]/[parameterized module]?

Comment: Once the lack of definition `type el = X.t` fixed, your example works for me (with and without parentheses)?

Comment: @octachron yes ... adding an explicit `type el = X.t` to the body of the method does make the OCaml program valid, but it also adds a new exported type to the interface ... so it isn't exactly equivalent to "just moving" the anonymous interface in the first example outside the functor definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to add `el` to the exports of the module then there are two ways:

1. Use a substitution constraint:

   ```ocaml
   ORDERED_PAIR_SET_TYPE with type el := X.t
   ```

   That will *remove* the specification of `el` from the signature.
2. Use a parameterised signature. Unfortunately, that is not expressible directly in OCaml, but requires a bit of extra functor gymnastics around the definition of your signature:

   ```ocaml
   module SET_TYPE (X : ORDERED_TYPE) =
   struct
     module type S =
       sig
         type t
         val get_fst : t -> X.el
         val get_snd : t -> X.el
         val make : X.el -> X.el -> t
         val compare : t -> t -> int
       end
     end
   ```

   With that you can write:

   ```ocaml
   module MakeOrderedPairSet (X : ORDERED_TYPE) : SET_TYPE(X).S = ...
   ```

Comment: For comparison ... does that mean you can write parameterized signatures in SML without using a wrapper module?

Comment: No, SML does not have that ability at all (although some SML dialects will allow you to write something similar to the above).